# Aws lambda deployment with zappa

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zappa

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: 
   An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: Lambda was unable to encrypt your environment variables because the KMS access was denied. Please check your KMS permissions. 
   KMS Exception: AccessDeniedException KMS Message: 
   User: arn:aws:iam::816087693535:user/pj@123.com is not authorized to perform: kms:Encrypt on resource: arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:816087693535:key/22a02ce6-2afe-4184-bfbf-18d72d238bdd with an explicit deny in a service control policy.
```

Also we tried to read and write kms policies but it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the IAM user pj@123.com to perform kms:Encrypt on the resource arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:816087693535:key/22a02ce6-2afe-4184-bfbf-18d72d238bdd If you have already tried that but it still doesn't work my next question would be if you are using AWS Organizations. If you do, I would visit AWS Organizations on the Management Account and check for any Service Control Policies (SCPs) which explicitly deny this action. If you follow these steps the resolution of your issue should be straightforward. Kindly let me know if not.